# What is the textual representation of possible options for e.g. versioning called?

Tags: git, text, pseudocode

I believe I read something a while ago, regarding a way to represent possible options in e.g. versioning.

Let's say that we have the following possibilities for versioning a GIT release branch.

- release-1.0.0-alpha
- release-1.0.0-beta
- release-1.0.0

Where the numbers of course can differ. One could write it down as follows:

`release-[major.minor.patch](-beta|-alpha)`. (I'm not sure if this is the correct notation).

Where the first three options (major, minor and patch) are mandatory. And the beta and alpha are optional. Where there is a choice of beta or alpha.

My question is, what is this type of notation called? I tried to google, but since I have no idea on what this type of notation is called, It's pretty hard to find anything.

Comment: On the topic of version numbers in particular, you could also look at https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/dpkg-dev/deb-version.5.en.html. The main idea is to be able to look at two version numbers and make a decision.

Comment: I will read the link post linked by you. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure bout your question.

If you are referring to the name about the versioning convention it is called **Semantic Versioning** (https://semver.org/)

If you are referring to the notation used to express possible optional, mandatory, or repeating elements... they are all simplified subset/variation of **regular expressions** notations.

The correct way should be in my opinion:

```
release-<major>.<minor>.<patch>[-alpha|-beta]
```

in this case I used angular brackets ('<' '>') to indicate not terminal elements, square brackets ('[' ']') to indicate optionality, and pipe ('|') to indicate alternatives.

-- edit after the comments:

If the "language" you have to define is very complex it could be better express it by means of a BNF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

Comment: I'm indeed referring to the second case. Is there any standard to this that you know of? I've updated my documentation to comply with the style suggested by you. Thanks!

I probably should have stated my question more clearly. Since referring to GIT is a bit confusing. As you already guessed correctly, I'm talking about the general way of writing down optional and mandatory options and variants. Sort of a pseudo-code style.

Comment: as said before the more common way is regular expressions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that are used both in specification and in implementation.
In case of "informal" specification you can relax the details as I did (not specifying for example that major, minor, and patch are digits).

If the "language" you have to define is very complex it could be better express it by means of a BNF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

Comment: Your reference to the Backus Naur form is exactly what I meant! It's been a long time since I read about it, so I forgot the name. Your explanation is very clear, thank you so much!